# Java. como exibir um vetor de string a partir da opção de um menu?

Tags: java

Eu criei 3 vetores, um para nome, e os outros para dia e mês de nascimento.

Eu preencho os 3 através da primeira opção do menu que fiz com o `switch case`, a segunda opção seria para exibir apenas os nomes de quem está cadastrado (inserido) no vetor de nomes: agenda, mas não dá certo, porém quando está fora da estrutura condicional dá certo.

Quando ponho em qualquer estrutura o vetor não é exibido, como se estivesse vazio. O que faço?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author lab1
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class q3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          int tecla = 1;
          while (tecla != 27){

          System.out.println("**********Agenda de aniversariantes**************");

        System.out.println("1.Cadastrar pessoa na agenda");
        System.out.println("2.Excluir pessoa a partir do nome");
        System.out.println("3.Consultar aniversariantes de uma data (dia e mês)");
        System.out.println("4.Consultar aniversariantes por mês");
        System.out.println("5.Consultar aniversariantes pela letra inicial do nome");
        System.out.println("6.Mostrar toda a agenda ordenada pelo nome");
        System.out.println("7.Mostrar toda a agenda ordenada pelo mes");
        System.out.println("8.Sair");
        System.out.println("A agenda pode suportar até 10 pessoas");


        String agenda[] = new String[10];
        int dia[] = new int[10];
        int mes[] = new int[10];
        System.out.print("Digite uma opção:");
        int opcao = scan.nextInt();

        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                int i = 0;

               // if(i < 10){
                    System.out.print("Digite o nome: ");
                    agenda[i] = scan.next();
                    System.out.print("Digite o dia do aniversario: ");
                    dia[i] = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Digite o mes do aniversario: ");
                    mes[i] = scan.nextInt();
                i++;
                //}
               // else
                 //   System.out.println("Agenda cheia");
            break;   
            case 2:
                int j;
                for (j=0;j<agenda.length;j++)
                if(agenda[0] == null)
                    System.out.println("Agenda vazia");
                else{
                    System.out.println("Agenda de aniversários");
                    for (j=0;j<agenda.length;j++){
                        System.out.println(agenda[j]);
                        System.out.println(dia[j]);
                        System.out.println(mes[j]);
                }
                }
            break;    
    }

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece por que você instancia os vetores toda vez que roda o `while`.

Segue a correção, feita trazendo as linhas dos vetores acima no código:

```
package br.com.alura.teste;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tecla = 1;

        //Preste atenção aqui: 
        String agenda[] = new String[10];
        int dia[] = new int[10];
        int mes[] = new int[10];
        while (tecla != 27) {

            System.out.println("**********Agenda de aniversariantes**************");

            System.out.println("1.Cadastrar pessoa na agenda");
            System.out.println("2.Excluir pessoa a partir do nome");
            System.out.println("3.Consultar aniversariantes de uma data (dia e mês)");
            System.out.println("4.Consultar aniversariantes por mês");
            System.out.println("5.Consultar aniversariantes pela letra inicial do nome");
            System.out.println("6.Mostrar toda a agenda ordenada pelo nome");
            System.out.println("7.Mostrar toda a agenda ordenada pelo mes");
            System.out.println("8.Sair");
            System.out.println("A agenda pode suportar até 10 pessoas");

            System.out.print("Digite uma opção:");
            int opcao = scan.nextInt();

            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                int i = 0;

                // if(i < 10){
                System.out.print("Digite o nome: ");
                agenda[i] = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Digite o dia do aniversario: ");
                dia[i] = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Digite o mes do aniversario: ");
                mes[i] = scan.nextInt();
                i++;
                // }
                // else
                // System.out.println("Agenda cheia");
                break;
            case 2:
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < agenda.length; j++)
                    if (agenda[0] == null)
                        System.out.println("Agenda vazia");
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Agenda de aniversários");
                        for (j = 0; j < agenda.length; j++) {
                            // E aqui também fiz uma pequena alteração
                            if(null != agenda[j]) {
                                System.out.println(agenda[j]);
                                System.out.println(dia[j]);
                                System.out.println(mes[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas quando adiciono outra pessoa, a mesma ocupa o lugar da pessoa anteriormente cadastrada

Comment: `int i = 0;`. É erro do seu código, não da sua duvida, mude essa linha para algum integer que conte a quantidade de usuarios inseridos.